# Principal ideal domain, $\forall x=(x_1,x_2)^t \in R^2~~\exists G \in SL_2(R) : Gx=(\gcd(x_1,x_2), 0)^t$

Tags: abstract-algebra, matrices, ring-theory, principal-ideal-domains

> Let $R$ be a principal ideal domain. Prove that for every $x=(x_1,x_2)^t \in R^2$ exists a matrix $G \in SL_2(R)$ for which $Gx=(\gcd(x_1,x_2), 0)^t$.

I think it's easy, but do not know how to start. Thanks.

Comment: You seem to be using () to denote more than one thing. Could you clarify the meanings?

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft this is task from my faculty workbook. I've fixed the problem, according to my understanding.

Comment: Note that you have Bezout's identity in principal ideal rings, which pretty much says what you need (well, with $SL_n$ replaced by $GL_n$ so you do need to work a little bit).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set $d=\gcd(x_1,x_2)$. Since $R$ is a PID there exist $a_1,a_2\in R$ such that $a_1x_1+a_2x_2=d$. Write $x_1=dy_1$, and $x_2=dy_2$. The matrix you are looking for is $$\left(\begin{array}{cc}a_1 &a_2\\-y_2 & y_1\end{array}\right).$$

Comment: Thanks, your answer is good! But we can write $y_1 = dx_1$, $y_2 = dx_2$, right?

Comment: @olegas How so? $d\mid x_1\Rightarrow\exists y_1:x_1=dy_1$